# Configuring "no-proxy" in Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: .net, configuration, fluent-nhibernate

Just a short question: How do I configure the many-to-one attribute "lazy" to the value "no-proxy" (as mentioned here [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/28/nhibernate-new-feature-no-proxy-associations.aspx) ) in Fluent Nhibernate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the answere [here](http://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/commit/92ad2d8c4ba8391c74fc8e32b36e71722b63dff0):

In your fluent overrides or mappings, just call

```
.LazyLoad(Laziness.NoProxy);
```

on the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Fluent NHibernate - Release notes 1.1](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Release_notes_1.1)

*[interface] No proxy lazy support*

Comment: I did find that, but how do I configure FNH to actually use this feature?